# How can one define a set of formulas inductively, without some base propositions being defined first?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, modal-logic, coalgebras

In some contexts (i.e. coalgebraic logic/coalgebraic modal logic) I see people commonly define (coalgebraic) languages (indeed sets of formulas) without considering any atomic propositions (or base formulas, in other words) first. I have never seen like this before this.

*How is that even possible? is it common in other branches of logic?*

Following you can see a glance from the paper "Expressive logics for coalgebras via terminal sequence induction" by someone expert of the field. **Please** don't be ignorant to the question just because it is about *coalgebras* and you have never seen them; this question doesn't seem to have much to do with that: you van even consider the boolean part not the modality, if you don't want the story coalgebraic.

[image]

**For those who are curious, $\Lambda$ is a set of predicate liftings for the signature functor.

Thanks.

Comment: Not to mention that there are versions that consider some atoms first, though it's bot common at all in the literature.

Comment: In your example there is in fact a base formula, as noted below the definition.

Comment: This is an inductive definition with a base case given by the empty conjunction. The fact that the semantics take values in a coalgebra is irrelevant. If you are having problems with coinductive definitions then ask a different question. And please avoid special pleading about how your question should be answered: it is pointless and annoying.